# Load serverside c# scripts and then attach a scripts to game object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have Two question.
1. How can I load existing c# scripts from external path to my apk file.
2. How can I attach scripts in a game object.
Assuming that I create a sphere and then build an apk file. when i run my unity app, you can see the sphere,which is not moving. After building apk file, i'd like to move the sphere .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scripts are compiled objects, so I believe you can't load them in dynamically. In addition, I believe Android wouldn't allow it anyway, as loading scripts in dynamically is considered a security risk. You could download an app, which downloads new virus-type scripts that weren't in the original code...

Answer (score 1):

you can attach C# script to game object and disable it(unchecked), and after build apk file you can enable it by a button in run time,

Comment: Try to avoid comment in answer unless you have specific detail answer. Please use comment box below and Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. :)